# Is there a Count function in Go but for overlapping substrings?

Tags: string, go, substring, overlap

Im using Go's `strings.Count(s, subtring)` function which works fine but it finds only the [`non-overlapping instances of subtring in s`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Count). Is there a function which finds the overlapping instances as well?

So for example

```
s := "ccc"
fmt.Println(strings.Count(s, "cc")) // returns 1 but I want 2 (there are 2 substrings s[0:1] and s[1:2])
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so offhand, but if you're not concerned with performance, it's trivial to write. `for i := 0; i < len(haystack) - len(needle); i++ { if strings.HasPrefix(haystack[i:], needle) { count++ } }`, more or less. To get better performance when the needle doesn't always occur in the haystack, copy the existing `Count` and change the `s = s[i+len(substr):]` to `s = s[i+1:]`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do it:

```
package main
import "strings"

func count(sub, pat string) int {
   var c int
   for d := range sub {
      if strings.HasPrefix(sub[d:], pat) { c++ }
   }
   return c
}

func main() {
   c := count("ccc", "cc")
   println(c == 2)
}
```

Note if Go had Regular Expression Lookahead, you could do something like this
Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> len(re.findall('(?=cc)', 'ccc'))
2
```